# Proper formatting for NASA API request URL

Tags: json, get, data.gov

**EDIT**: NASA data can be accessed via the SODA API (see https://data.nasa.gov/developer), and the API referred to below seems to be deprecated.

I'm trying to use the NASA API (http://nasa.github.io/api-docs/#introduction) to pull information on NASA patents. The docs show what the JSON reponse should look like and list required parameters for the request, but I can't find any examples of a properly formed request URL. So far I have tried (with my API key):

```
https://api.nasa.gov/patents/optics?api_key=API_KEY

https://api.nasa.gov/patents/optics.json?api_key=API_KEY
```

I tested the API key out on an example GET request URL for a different data.gov agency and it returned a valid JSON response, but I've had no luck with the NASA requests.

Does anyone know the proper request format for NASA info from the data.gov API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there may be a be a better api to use that is actually on NASA's site here: https://data.nasa.gov/developer.

If you scroll down to "NASA Patents" you can see some documentation on how to use the api and a few sample requests to get you started, including how to filter on specific fields.

Comment: Thanks @tokkov, I overlooked that page. Looks like the API I was trying to use may be obsolete since NASA is now using the SODA API.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the API documentation, it would seem that the category name (like `optics` in your example), should be passed a query parameter, not as part of URI as you are showing.  I also don't see noted where they say they support https (of course I just skimmed the API). Try,

```
http://api.nasa.gov/patents?category=optics&api_key=API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks @mike-bryant, but it looks like NASA has moved to the SODA API